# How to show remaining time in digital clock?

Tags: android, clock

am creating one application for student. I need to show digital clock with remaining time.
here i add digital clock
 [image]
 but it show system date
and i need to show Remaining time means suppose if exam time is 10 minute then it must show
 time in reverse manner.  Or i need to use another clock.
Any help is Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define this code in onCreate.

```
// 5000 is the starting number (in milliseconds)
// 1000 is the number to count down each time (in milliseconds)
MyCount counter = new MyCount(5000, 1000);
counter.start();
```

Constructor for CountDownTimer is as follow.

```
// countdowntimer is an abstract class, so extend it and fill in methods
public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{

public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
tv.setText(”done!”);   //TextView object should be defined in onCreate
}

    @Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
tv.setText(”Left: ” + millisUntilFinished/1000);// This will be called every Second.

}
}
```

Comment: Can u have a reference from this site. http://w2davids.wordpress.com/simple-countdowntimer-example/

Comment: i think you can write in onTick(). inside that you will have to divide millisUntilFinish so that you will get whole time

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`CountDownTimer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)-class.